# How to add banner image to wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a website using wordpress.. I want to add banner image to my site background. I don't know how to add this because I am a beginner. Can anyone Help me..

I expect like this[click here](http://www.hubspot.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Usage of the Advance Custom field plugin will help you to solve the problem.

Since in the ACF you can create Banner Images for the pages also. You can have a separate field to upload the banner images and you can display it in the place where you want.

Reference: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Using this plugin you can do magics onto WordPress...

Image Sceenshot:

[image]

Comment: If so you are flexible of using this plugin let us work it on to fix this issue... You have to display the image as absolute and over to that you need to add the Codes that you want :)

Comment: ,Without using plugin, How to add such a banner images to site?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can you say What code i need to add and where i need to add?

Comment: You need to display the BG image to all pages in your site or what :)

Comment: currently I am having one page on my new site.. So I need to add on that page only..

Comment: For that alone i said you to use that plugin and you can change the image dynamically as and when needed. And it will be dynamic too.

Comment: plugin is the easiest way to use.. But i want to know how to fix it without plugin..

Comment: Is there any other way to fix banner image on my site??

Comment: You want to add Dynamic Banner or Static Banner to the Page that you have created.Clarify me that...

Comment: If you mentions this it will be easy to solve your issue sister :)

Comment: Static banner is enough for me..

Comment: Shall i provide one static page with the sample so that you can make it for your site..

Comment: I will provide you with the sample banner for the page and you can replicate it for your site too in which page you needed. Or shall you provide me the code of the page in which you want to integrate. :)

Comment: Can u send the sample banner which you have?

Comment: Can you post the Page ID where you want the banner image to appear.

Comment: Can you suggest one theme to use such a banner..

Comment: Now I am using twentysixteen theme which is default theme in wordpress

Comment: You can do it using the header.php file and it seems one of the easiest method

Comment: Post you page ID in which you want to display. Since the header file will be called in all the pages you can customize using the header.php file.

Comment: Shall i continue with that theme itself?

Comment: Ya no issues in that. You can control in any theme as per your request :)

Comment: Have you found the solution sister :) I have found the method

Comment: No still I didn't get any solution.

Comment: You know to write style based on `position:absolute` and `position:relative`ah sister if i display the image alone in your page

Comment: Ya I can change the position brother.

Comment: Image added by editing the Question. Have a look whether in that area if you get image it is okie for you sister :)

Comment: I want that content should be placed on that image.. Image should look like background of that content..

Comment: Ya you can make the image as `position:absolute;` and the content as `position:relative;` which can solve your trick

Comment: Thank you brother Its working... but at the corner i am having black screen..

Comment: Glad to help you sister:) Feeling happy that you got the output.